# How efficient is a PHP image resource?

Tags: php, php-gd, memory-efficient

I have a very large PNG image, and I am writing a method to get the value for a color at a specific (but changing) pixel of that image.  When I create the image using:

```
$image = imagecreatefrompng('map.png');
```

Is the whole image loaded into memory (not ideal), or does it just read the meta data and prepare for other calls so that when I call:

```
int imagecolorat ( resource $image , int $x , int $y )
```

Will it file seek to the right pixel or pull from memory?  If I'm trying to optimize this routine to be called repeatedly, would I be better off converting the image data I need into some raw binary format and using file seek?  I'd like to avoid repeatedly loading the whole file into memory if possible.

Comment: The entire image is loaded into memory, at 4 bytes per pixel; any manipulation will typically require double that amount of memory

Comment: @MarkBaker - Sounds like an answer not a comment :)  Put it below and I'll give you the check.  (Bummer BTW, it makes sense because with compression the exact location of a pixel inside a file wouldn't be known.)  Looks like I'll have to convert it to a flat file and use fopen / fseek

Comment: There used to be a PHP extension called PHPqb (the web site seems dead now http://php-qb.net/) that was designed for highly memory-efficient manipulation of images, though it is still available through [PECL](https://pecl.php.net/package/qb)

Answer (score 0):

You need a big php memory to play with php image resources. 
Use graphicsMagick instead. http://www.graphicsmagick.org/

Comment: Not really trying to do image manipulation, what I'm actually trying to do is to get a number of geographic features for a specific coordinate.  Elevation has a Google API, but I need things like tree density -- The only sources of these seem to be massive grayscale TIFF files.  Basically, I'm going to have to convert them into something that resembles an 8 bit BMP (0 compression) so that I can know mathematically which byte to access to get the value I need.